# Restaurar o reconectar conexion de base de datos

Tags: java, java-swing, java-ee

Tengo una aplicacion de escritorio desarrolada en Java, su base de datos en esta online en un servidor. El problema es cuando se pierde la conexion a internet la aplicacion muestra el siguiente mensaje de error:

**java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed**

Necesito volver a reconectarme sin tener que salir de la aplicacion.

La aplicacion utiliza el metodo de conexion **singleton** que consiste en utilizar una sola conexion y reutilizarla.

Utilizo el conector **mysql-connector-java-8.0.24.jar**

Ejemplo:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Conexion {
    
   private static Connection con = null;
   public static Connection getConnection(){
      try{
         if( con == null ){            
            //Conexion Online
            String driver="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"; //el driver 
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://ip:3306/test?useCompresion=true&autoReconnet=true&useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8";
            String usuario = "root";
            String password = "root";
            
            Class.forName(driver);
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,usuario,password);
          
         }
     }
     catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error Conexion a la Base de Datos "+ex);
         
     }
     return con;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Las conexiones de base de datos son un recurso externo, el cual puede cambiar de estatus sin que el lenguaje de programación se entere.

Es una mala práctica de programación crear conexiones a base de datos de tipo estático. La razón es que si la conexión esta mucho tiempo abierta sin utilizarse el manejador de base de datos la puede colocar como inactiva y el lenguaje de programación no logra enterarse y actualizar dicho estatus. Al tratar de usar una conexión que paso a estatus inactivo en el manejador de base de datos ocurre la excepción que reportas. No es el único tipo de excepción que suele ocurrir pero si es uno de los mas comunes.

Debido a que suelen ocurrir este tipo de problemas, también es una mala práctica programar una aplicación con una conexión que este abierta todo el tiempo. La forma correcta es abrir la conexión, hacer las operaciones requeridas de base de datos e inmediatamente cerrar la conexión. Para una siguiente operación la conexión debe volver a abrirse, realizar las acciones necesarias y volver a cerrarse. La única excepción para mantener una conexión abierta es cuando usas una transacción. Aquí la conexión debe mantenerse abierta en lo que dura la transacción y su confirmación o rechazó. Una vez terminada la transacción debe cerrarse la conexión y volver a abrirse cuando se  vaya a usar de nuevo.

Todo lo que comento solo son buenas prácticas que he adquirido con la experiencia, no quiere decir que no se pueda hacer de otras formas, pero estas practicas ayudan a que nunca veas errores como el que te esta ocurriendo.

**En resumen:**

*Malas prácticas:*

Conexiones estáticas.

Conexiones abiertas todo el tiempo.

*Buenas practicas:*

Abrir una conexión, usarla y cerrarla inmediatamente después de que hizó su operación.

Abrir y cerrar conexiones para cada operación que se vaya a hacer.

Mantener conexión abierta solo si se esta usando una transacción y cerrarla una vez terminada la transacción.